# getting error "not all arguments converted during string formatting - Python"

Tags: python

I ma using csv file to fetch some data for automatic login. In my first file, lets call it core.py, i am defining it as function.Here is my code :

```
import csv
def csvTodict():
    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)     
    filename = os.path.join(dir, './testdata/InputData.csv') 
    with open(filename) as f:
        logins = dict(filter(None, csv.reader(f)))
    return logins
```

and in another file, i am calling the values for username and password : Its my modules.py

```
from core import *
fnsignin()

def fnsignin():
try:
   myDict=csvTodict()
   fnLogin(myDict["Username"],myDict["Password"]
```

But when i run, I am getting error " `not all arguments converted during string formatting`". I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Please help

Comment: could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: How does your CSV look, and what does `fnLogin` do?